# Resolving 504 error in Sitecore at scaling out

Tags: azure, paas

I have a question regarding app service warmup. We’re experiencing frequent gateway timeout during CD app service scale-out events.
The problem is that the instance starts serving on the root to the App service load-balancer, but is not yet fully warmed up on other paths, which might take so much time to reply, that it results in a gateway timeout event. We were exploring options like IIS native applicationIntialization, but it works on http only. We’ve found out, that we get the best performance using just Azure-native health-checks, but they can check just one path (root by default).

We were thinking about possibility of building a standalone static site, which would use all features used on other sites this CD instance serves, that we could use as a reliable health-probe. Meaning, this path would be available only in case everything else already is. Sitecore would basically check itself and let the load-balancer know once it thinks it’s ready by serving the probe site.

Do you have experience with any solution like this, or do you recommend a different one that would help us?

Comment: Did you configure applicationInitializer URL's? https://blog.baslijten.com/warmup-your-application-on-azure-app-service-when-scaling-up-and-swapping-slots-using-application-initialization/

Comment: It actually uses http. But my ops team want a way with https.

Comment: When using an AGW you can probably just disable sslOnly on your App Services.